# Is there a way to edit existing text in an existing PowerPoint slide using PptxGenJS

Tags: pptxgenjs

I have never used this tool before but I want to know if it would be a good idea to use this tool

Will I be able to take an existing slide and edit one line of text using PptxGenJS

[Image of slide and text I want to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB8m9.png)

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not supported. You can only create pptx files not edit them.